# How to I get the index of a subscribed object in Angular component file?

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscribe

```
this.arrName.subscribe(data, (index as i) => { //fake implementation
    let myData = data.inside[i].keyName;
});
```

I want to implement something like this.

Comment: What do you mean by "the index"? Are you referring to items in an array, or to a stream of objects received by the subscribe callback?

Comment: I guess you need to elaborate a bit more. Try posting some sample data coming as response. What is index here and is it based on some input from UI?

Comment: "data" is an object having an array of objects called "inside". For example

data = {
    inside: [{key: value}, {key:value}]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
this.arrName.subscribe(data => {
   for(let i in data.inside){
    let myData = data.inside[i].keyName;
  }
});
```

but you need data as

```
{ 
 inside : [
             {keyName: ...}
          ]
}
```

as `data.inside[i]` access `i`th index of data.inside, or if you have data as array use `data[i]`

Comment: Happy to help :-), please accept the answer if it helped .